# Can i simplify following math expression?

Tags: summation

I have following expression: $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10^2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10^3}\right\rfloor+\ldots+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10^{\lfloor\log_{10} n\rfloor}}\right\rfloor$ where $n$ is a positive integer, greater than $0$

Can this expressoin be somehow simplified? If yes - how?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consider the decimal expansion of $n$. The first term is obtained from $n$ by deleting the rightmost digit, the second by deleting the rightmost $2$ etc., while the last term is just the leftmost digit. For example, with $n=123$ your sum is $12+1=13$.

Write $n=\sum_{i=0}^k a_i 10^i$, with integer coefficients $0\le a_i\le 9,\,a_k\ne 0$. The desired sum is $$\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{i=j}^k a_i 10^{i-j}=\sum_{i=0}^k a_i(\sum_{j=1}^i 10^{i-j})=\sum_{i=0}^k a_i\tfrac{10^i - 1}{9}=\tfrac{n-\sum_i a_i}{9}.$$Note that $\sum_i a_i$ is the sum of digits of $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative response. To compute the expression I have mentioned in my question, it is required approximately logarithmic number of mathematical operations. While your formula looks small, we need to calculate each individual digits from number `n`, which will also take logarithmic number of mathematical operations and in this sense the complexity of above two expressions are the same. I should have mentioned this in my question but i forgot: Could there be a way of simplification, that will also reduce the number of required mathematical oparations?

Comment: @blindProgrammer I sincerely doubt it. It's rare for problems to have $o(\log n)$ solutions. In this case, any such solution could be used to sum the digits of $n$ faster than the usual way, which makes the idea less likely.